# Getting SharePoint Server 2013 to accept a .html page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, html, file, iframe

Now I have a .html page I want share point to accept. In my list of web pages, I have had to change the extensions to .aspx which I am not happy with. Is there a simple setting I have to do to get the HTML page to work with share point or does share point only work with .aspx web pages?

The reason I want to keep it HTML is because I am using  on the HTML and for the life of me cannot understand how to get .aspx pages in SharePoint to accept them. whenever I edit the source or embedded it, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a security measure on the SharePoint-side. [This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8073.sharepoint-browser-file-handling-deep-dive.aspx) has some details about this.

In short: You can configure this the "simple" way for a SPWebApplication and set `Browser File Handling` to `permissive` (thus allowing html and other mimetypes) using the `SharePoint central administration`

Go to `manage WebApplications` in the central administration:
[image: Go to <code>manage WebApplications</code> in the central administration]

Select a WebApplication, then `General Settings`:
[image: Select a WebApplication, then <code>General Settings</code>]

Alternatively you can allow *only* html, by using PowerShell (this needs to run on a server, which is part of the SharePoint-Farm, using the `SharePoint Management Shell`):

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://path.to.your.webApp/
$webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add('text/html')
$webApp.Update()
```

Comment: is this something I have to do on the server machine itself or is this a setting I can set in sharepoint ?

Comment: The PowerShell has to be done on the server - the "permissive" setting can be done using SharePoint, however you'll need to be farm-admin to access the central adminitration. I have update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting it as an aspx page. that made SharePoint accept the page and display it.